# sfdisk can't create more than 4 partitions?

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos-6

I'm running Centos 6 from command line, and I need to partition my disk using sfdisk more than 5 times.  However I can't seem to create more than 4 partitions.

```
>> sfdisk <scsi ID> --force -uB
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
OK

Disk /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123: 14593 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Old situation:
Units = blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot   Start       End    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part1            0+ 117220823  117220823+  83  Linux
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part2            0         -          0    0  Empty
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part3            0         -          0    0  Empty
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part4            0         -          0    0  Empty
Input in the following format; absent fields get a default value.
<start> <size> <type [E,S,L,X,hex]> <bootable [-,*]> <c,h,s> <c,h,s>
Usually you only need to specify <start> and <size> (and perhaps <type>).

/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part1 :0,4194303,L
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part1            0+  4194302    4194302+  83  Linux
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part2 :,18833774,L
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part2      4194303  23028076   18833774   83  Linux
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part3 :,23548186,L
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part3     23028077  46576262   23548186   83  Linux
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part4 :,23548186,L
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part4     46576263  70124448   23548186   83  Linux
New situation:
Units = blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot   Start       End    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part1            0+  4194302    4194302+  83  Linux
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part2      4194303  23028076   18833774   83  Linux
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part3     23028077  46576262   23548186   83  Linux
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-123-part4     46576263  70124448   23548186   83  Linux
Warning: partition 1 does not end at a cylinder boundary
Do you want to write this to disk? [ynq]
```

After specifying the 4th partition, sfdisk automatically prompts me to write the partition information or not.  I still have at least 3 more partitions I want to create though.

Is there anyway to continue to partition the disk using this method so that I can have more than 4 partitions?

Answer (score 0):

The *man page* for *sfdisk states:

> sfdisk doesn't understand the GUID Partition Table (GPT) format and it is not designed for large partitions.  In these cases use the more advanced GNU parted(8).

MS-DOS partition tables (the standard before GPT, which you are using) only allow four primary partitions, that's where that limit comes from. Still, you can make one (and only one!) of those four partitions an *extended* partition, which means it can be further subdivided into *secondary* partitions.

Also, *sfdisk* is not the best instrument available: again *its own man page* (!!) states:

> sfdisk  has  four (main) uses: list the size of a partition, list the partitions on a device, check the partitions on a device, and - very dangerous - repartition a device.
>
> CAUTION WARNINGS:
>          The options marked with caution in the manual page are dangerous.  For example not all functionality is
>          completely implemented, which can be a reason for unexpected results.

A list of bugs follows.

I strongly suggest you move on to *parted*, or to *gparted* if you feel more comfortable with a GUI.